# Sed print nextline and change it

Tags: sed

My file:

```
"gd$postalAddress":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
"$t":"randomtext"}]}
"gd$postalAddress":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
"$t":"randomtext222"}]}
"title":{"type":"text"
"$t":"randomtext"}
"gd$postalAddress":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
"$t":"randomtext"}]}
```

I need to change $t on the line after postalAddress but not $t after the line with title.

This will print the lines i want to change.

```
sed -n '/postalAddress/ {n;p}' file.txt
```

This will print the line i want to change, with the change included:

```
sed -n '/postalAddress/ {n;p}' file.txt | sed 's/"$t":"/CHANGE/'
```

But how do i change this in my file ?

Here's how my file should look like:

```
"gd$postalAddress":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
"CHANGE":"randomtext"}]}
"gd$postalAddress":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
"CHANGE":"randomtext222"}]}
"title":{"type":"text"
"$t":"randomtext"}
"gd$postalAddress":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
"CHANGE":"randomtext"}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
sed '/postalAddress/{n;s/\$t/CHANGE/;}' file
"gd$postalAddress":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
"CHANGE":"randomtext"}]}
"gd$postalAddress":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
"CHANGE":"randomtext222"}]}
"title":{"type":"text"
"$t":"randomtext"}
"gd$postalAddress":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
"CHANGE":"randomtext"}]}
```

With `awk` you can do:

```
awk '/postalAddress/ {print;getline;sub(/\$t/,"CHANGE")}1' file
"gd$postalAddress":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
"CHANGE":"randomtext"}]}
"gd$postalAddress":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
"CHANGE":"randomtext222"}]}
"title":{"type":"text"
"$t":"randomtext"}
"gd$postalAddress":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
"CHANGE":"randomtext"}]}
```

Using flag with `awk`:

```
awk '/postalAddress/ {f=NR+1} f==NR {sub(/\$t/,"CHANGE");f=0}1 file
```

Answer (score 0):

You really ought to do this using a language that understands your data, which appears to be JSON, so perhaps Python.  But we can do it using sed:

```
sed '/}]}/ s/"$t":"/CHANGE/' file.txt

"gd$postalAddress":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
CHANGErandomtext"}]}
"gd$postalAddress":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
CHANGErandomtext222"}]}
"title":{"type":"text"
"$t":"randomtext"}
"gd$postalAddress":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
CHANGErandomtext"}]}
```

This relies on the punctuation being the way it is on the end of the lines you care about, and not on the ones you don't.

Comment: Thank you, but i can't really do this based on the punctuation. The only way i can identify the change is based on the line after postaladdress.

Comment: Output is not what OP want, you have just looked at the `sed` he posted, and not what he like to have.